# Conditional Statements(php) between html attributes?

Tags: php, html

I'm refactoring a php web page and I need to insert a class dynamically.

By structure of the project, one solution is put a ternary operator `<?($selectedElement=="KeyOne"? 'linkactive': 'normalLink') ?>` to handle the value of a variable assigned before:

```
<a id="customid_generatebytool" class="<?($selectedElement=="KeyOne"? 'linkactive': 'normalLink') ?>" href="anotherPage.php" ...>
....
</a>

<a id="customid_generatebytool" class="<?($selectedElement=="KeyTwo"? 'linkactive': 'normalLink') ?>" href="Page2.php" ...>
....
</a>
```

But my code above doesn't work, I'm new in php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `echo`.

```
<a id="customid_generatebytool" class="<?php echo ($selectedElement=="KeyOne"? 'linkactive': 'normalLink') ?>" href="anotherPage.php" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used php short tags `<?`. Make sure it's enabled in your php.ini.